# In Mongoose, the method save(); don't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

When I try to save anything in mongo using mongoose, the callback of method save(); return me OK, this would mean that everything is saved in MongoDB but when I check MongoDB in console there not anything saved just de DB empty. Notably, I use mongo on docker container.

Conecction.ts

```js
import  mongoose from 'mongoose';

const DB_URL:string = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

mongoose.connect(DB_URL,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    user:'admin',
    pass:'qwerty12345',
    dbName:'veterinaria_db'
});


export default mongoose.connection
```

Client.ts

```js
import  mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema:any = mongoose.Schema;
import db from '../db/Conecction';


db.on('error',console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open',()=>{
    console.log('DB: Connected Susesfuly!!');
});

export interface IClient extends mongoose.Document{
    name:string,
    first_last_name:string,
    second_last_name:string,
    username:string,
    password:string,
    mail:string,
    phone:string,
    cellphone:string,
    history:[{
        appoinments:{
            pets:{
                name:string,
                type:string,
                age:number
            },
            date:Date,
            reason:string,
            status:number
        }
    }]
};

export const ClientSchema = Schema({
    name:String,
    first_last_name:String,
    second_last_name:String,
    username:String,
    password:String,
    mail:String,
    phone:String,
    cellphone:String,
    history:[{
        appoinments:{
            pets:{
                name:String,
                type:String,
                age:Number
            },
            date:Date,
            reason:String,
            status:Number
        }
    }]
});


export default db.model<IClient>('Client',ClientSchema);
```

Controller.ts

```js
    testPost(req: any, res: any) {
        let { name, first_last_name, second_last_name, username, password, mail, phone, cellphone, history } = req.body;
        let newClient = new Client({
            name,
            first_last_name,
            second_last_name,
            username,
            password,
            mail,
            phone,
            cellphone,
            history:[]
        });

        newClient.save((error, client) => {
            if (error) return res.status(500).send({ message: `Error: ${error}` });
            res.status(200).send({ message: `Client ${client.name} saved` });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if the first line from post is the problem.

let { name, first_last_name, second_last_name, username, password, mail, phone, cellphone, history } = req.body;

leave this line and do, if it is delivered as json:
let newClient = new Client(req.body);

what will be logged when you console.log in error and !error ?